# How to disable graphics in spacemacs, so that I can use like a terminal emacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am not sure if I am asking it right. I wanted to load spacemacs without graphic layer. So that it loads like a regular emacs inside terminal, where the colour, background will be the same as default terminal's. But I want all other spacemacs configurations.

Comment: Not sure about spacemacs, but the `-nw` option (`--no-window-system`) does precisely this with emacs.

Comment: Yeah. But in spacemacs that doesn't help.

Comment: Well, I've been using spacemacs for a long time in the terminal and there's absolutely no problem with the -nw option. Can you provide some details about you environment?